# wildcard subdomain routing ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7

I'm looking for a way to route wildcard subdomains to controllers in ASP MVC 4.

So something like this:

> CompanyName.mydomain.com

would need to translate into this:

> mydomain.com/CompanyName

I can't find any info on how to do this and I'm stuck. Is this a IIS thing or a ASP MVC routing thing?

Comment: try using the IIS rewrite module, specifically redirect rules -http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module

Comment: Hi Jeff, thx for the response, would this mean that a user gets redircted once he goes to CompanyName.mydomain.com and his browser bar would afterwards show mydomain.com/CompanyName ? Because if that's the case and from what I understood it is, that is not what I need. It needs to stay CompanyName.mydomain.com

Comment: yes, that would do a client redirect... for your scenario, try defining a rewrite rule instead (first section in the same document in my previous comment)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So after quite some time I solved this issue by myself on the application level.
IIS rewrites werent working, ASP MVC wasnt matching the right route and it would 404 out.

The solution that worked for me in the end was to make my own implementation of the route class, one that searches the hostname for a parametar and maps it as a route parametar. It works flawlessly now and the custom implemenation is simple. I fell in love with the flexibilty ASP MVC gives you in the process :)

So a custom route needs two overrides one for the method "GetRouteData" which matches an incoming route and the second one "GetVirtualPath" that writes outgoing routes.

Here is the whole custom route class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace System.Web.Routing
{
public class WildcardRoute : Route
{


    public WildcardRoute(string url, IRouteHandler handler)
        : base(url, handler)
    { 

    }
    public WildcardRoute(string url, RouteValueDictionary defaults, IRouteHandler handler)
        : base(url, defaults, handler)
    {
    }

    public WildcardRoute(string url, RouteValueDictionary defaults, RouteValueDictionary constraints, IRouteHandler handler)
        : base(url, defaults, constraints, handler)
    { 
    }

    public WildcardRoute(string url, RouteValueDictionary defaults, RouteValueDictionary constraints, RouteValueDictionary dataTokens, IRouteHandler handler)
        : base(url, defaults, constraints, dataTokens, handler)
    {

    }


    public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        // save the original path before we edit it
        var orignalPath = HttpContext.Current.Request.Path;

        //split the hostname
        var split = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host.Split('.');
        // fire only if there is more than 2 items in the split (company.mydomain.com) and if the first one is not www
        if (split.Count() > 2 && split[0].ToLower() != "www")
        {
            var split2 = HttpContext.Current.Request.Path.Split('/'); // split everything  after the hostname into segments
            string newPath = "/" + split[0]; // take the company from company.mydomain.com and rewrite it to mydomain.com/company
            foreach (var item in split2) // add all the other segments that come after mydomain.com/company 
            {                            // end result might be for example - mydomain.com/company/Home/Index 
                newPath = newPath + "/" + item;
            }
            httpContext.RewritePath(newPath); // rewrite the path into the newone
        }

        RouteData data = base.GetRouteData(httpContext); // match the route with the new path
        if (data == null) // if there is no match in this route write the path back to the original one
        {
            httpContext.RewritePath(orignalPath);
        }
        return data;
    }

    public override VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext, RouteValueDictionary values)
    {

        var data = base.GetVirtualPath(requestContext, values); // do the original url write
        var split = requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Host.Split('.'); // split the host by '.'

        var item = requestContext.RouteData.Values.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "PermalinkTitle"); // the PermalinkTitle is the name of the "company" route value in mydomain.com/company in my implementation
        if (split.Count() > 0 && split[0].ToLower().Contains(item.Value.ToString().ToLower())) // fire only if the hostname contains the "company" route value
        {
            data.VirtualPath = data.VirtualPath.Replace(item.Value.ToString(), "");
            if (data.VirtualPath.StartsWith("/"))
                data.VirtualPath = data.VirtualPath.Substring(1);
            // this code removes the company part from the path so we dont get company.mydomain.com/company/controller/action rather we just get company.mydomain.com/controller/action
        }
        return data;
    }

}
}
```

This implementation is flexible enough that its gonna work with all of these routes - "company.mydomain.com", "mydomain.com/company" and "www.mydomain.com/company".

After you made your custom route class you need to extend the RouteCollection with a Map method that maps your custom type of route, you also need to extend the AreaRegistrationContext if you use Areas, becouse with areas route mapping goes through that. Here is the whole implementation:

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace System.Web.Routing
{
    public static class WildcardRoutesExtension
    {

        public static WildcardRoute MapWildcardRoute(this RouteCollection routes, string name, string url, object defaults)
        {

            WildcardRoute route = new WildcardRoute(
                url,
                new RouteValueDictionary(defaults),
                new MvcRouteHandler());
            routes.Add(name, route);

            return route;
        }

        public static WildcardRoute MapWildcardRoute(this AreaRegistrationContext context, string name, string url, object defaults)
        {
                        WildcardRoute route = new WildcardRoute(
                url,
                new RouteValueDictionary(defaults),
                new RouteValueDictionary(new {}),
                new RouteValueDictionary(new {Area = context.AreaName }),
                new MvcRouteHandler());

            context.Routes.Add(name, route);
            return route;
        }


        public static WildcardRoute MapWildcardRoute(this AreaRegistrationContext context, string name, string url, object defaults, object constraints)
        {
            WildcardRoute route = new WildcardRoute(
                url,
                new RouteValueDictionary(defaults),
                new RouteValueDictionary(constraints),
                new RouteValueDictionary(new {Area = context.AreaName }),
                new MvcRouteHandler());

            context.Routes.Add(name, route);
            return route; 
        }

        public static WildcardRoute MapWildcardRoute(this RouteCollection routes, string name, string url, object defaults, object constraints)
        {
            WildcardRoute route = new WildcardRoute(
                url,
                new RouteValueDictionary(defaults),
                new RouteValueDictionary(constraints),

                new MvcRouteHandler());
            routes.Add(name, route);
            return route;
        }
    }
}
```

When you have all of this you now just need to map your custom routes like this for regular routes in the RouteConfig class:

```
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {


                 // rest of your routes

                routes.MapWildcardRoute(
                          name: "Default",
                          url: "{PermalinkTitle}/{controller}/{action}",
                          defaults: new {  }
                 );

              //Rest of your routes
        }
```

or like this for areas in the Areas AreaRegistration class:

```
    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {

        context.MapWildcardRoute(
            "MyArea_default",
            "{PermalinkTitle}/MyArea/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

    }
```

Comment: I had the same requirement as yours and your solution above is good and works perfectly, except for one small issue i.e. the virtual url does not get properly generated for the home page for @Url.Action("Index", "Home"). Kindly let me know if you have any solution for this, as i tried my best to get this resolved in the "GetVirtualPath" method.

Comment: How do you run this in localhost? `*.localhost` == 404

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this rule for IIS:

```
<rule name="Rule1" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(?!www)(.*)\.mydomain\.com$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://mydomain.com/{C:1}/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```

Comment: -1 - I think OP wants the client to see the CompanyName.mydomain.com domain all the time. Redirect doesn't therefore seem a valid answer.

Comment: Ok, rewrite action type can be used.

Comment: unfortunatly rewrite didnt work :( ASP MVC wasnt routing it properly, it worked with a redirect but thats not what I wanted. I solved it on the application level with a custom route implementation which I posted in detail in an answer

Answer (score 0):

I would say that mostly it has to do with both.
In most cases a subdomain is really a folder off of your root on the domain server.
(i.e., CompanyName.mydomain.com is usually a mydomain.com/CompanyName folder (just like you wrote it)).

Then, it would be up to your mvc routing to set up the routes as you desire them.
With mvc routing I use this direction: controller/action.

IIS will do the translation of getting you in to your CompanyName folder as your root for the subdomain. Your mvc would only need to have a home controller inside of that folder's controllers folder to navigate there, using either of your url definitions.